# does mXparser support string compare and substring built in function?

Tags: string, function

I'm using mXparser to evaluate expressions. Now i need support for string compare and sub-string
built in function. i can't find anything about strings in the documentation.
what i need is something like the substring in the below function

isOfCategoryX ( SKU, X ) = if ( substring(SKU,3,2) = X , 1 , 0 )

Answer (score 0):

Currently string values are not supported

- [issues 181](https://github.com/mariuszgromada/MathParser.org-mXparser/issues/181)
- [issues 174](https://github.com/mariuszgromada/MathParser.org-mXparser/issues/174)
- [issues 4](https://github.com/mariuszgromada/MathParser.org-mXparser/issues/4)

Best regards

Comment: thanks for the reply. can you recommend any parser that supports string values?